# PHP: preg_match -> Numbers and ONE hyphen

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I want a regex that accepts ONLY letters and ONE hyphen. The value has to start with 5- (five and one hyphen) and just 5-15 numbers after.

I'm currently using: `preg_match('/^[5]-{1}[\0-9]{5,15}$/', $_POST['value'])`

A valid value is: 5-123456789

My regex accepts two hyphens like 5--123456789. It has to start with 5, ONE hyphen and 5-15 numbers. How should I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you specified the digits wrong: `[\0-9]` matches any character whose index is between zero and that of `9` -- in ASCII terms, characters with indexes 0 to 57. The hyphen has an index of 45, so it's allowed. This happens because `\0` is interpreted as an [octal escape](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html) sequence.

You should use `[0-9]{5,15}` or `\d{5,15}` instead. You can also simplify the regex somewhat; `/^5-\d{5,15}$/` is correct and shorter.

Comment: @Treps: `[0-9]` is not wrong, but `[\0-9]` (extra backslash) is.

Comment: Ahaaaa! It's working btw. Good, I can use `[0-9]` and `\d`. :) Do you also know how to build a regex that just contains letters and numbers with `{5,15}`. It should accept both lower or uppercase letters, but it must contains letter, numbers and `{5,15}`.

Comment: @Treps: This is very basic syntax that really any tutorial will cover for you. Perhaps you mean `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}`, but I 'm not sure and in any case a reference would serve you better.

Comment: Yeah I know, but is doesn't work for me.. Now I use `preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}/', $_POST['value'])` and it accepts like "dsfsdfsdf". It should accept it if the value contains a number.

Comment: @Treps: Use positive looakead: `/^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}$/`.

Comment: Hmm, (?=.*\d) ? It's almost working btw. Only issue is that this preg_match accepts over 15 characters. I use it like this: `preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}/', $_POST['value'])`

Comment: @Treps: The one I gave does not match over 15. Go to a reference and find out what each part of the regex means.

Comment: Doesn't `{5,15}` mens 5-15 characters? Or have I misunderstood that? because minimal 5 characters does work.

Comment: @Treps: What is the difference between the two versions? The `$` at the end. What does `$` do? It anchors at the end of the output. What happens if you remove the `$`? The regex will match anything that *begins with* the target instead of only something that *is* the target.

Comment: Ahaa so $ is the key in this case. Learned something new. But I still don't know what `^(?=.*\d)` means. `\d` menas numbers/digits.

Comment: @Treps: I have suggested looking it up numerous times, and I mentioned that construct is called "positive lookahead" exactly so that you know what to look for. I also included a link to a very informative site in the answer. Taken together, all of these should be more than enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You used \ before 0, that means that it's not a range 0-9 but 0 and -9, so this is your second hyphen here (but it's optional, cause in brackets []). Just remove this \ from brackets. Leave it like this:

```
preg_match('/^[5]-{1}[0-9]{5,15}$/', $_POST['value'])
```

Even this notation is correct:

```
preg_match('/^5-[0-9]{5,15}$/', $_POST['value'])
```

Comment: "0 and -9"? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: In this case it's a bit tricker. As Jon described in his edit, it's actually that `\0` maps to ASCII value zero. So the `-` is still being interpreted as a range.